# ¿Como resetear un input tipo file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

tengo un problema con el siguiente código, lo que quiero hacer es que si la imagen es mayor de 3.67 MB, le de un  aviso al usuario de que es muy grande, y que no seleccione la imagen, ya que cuando da la alerta al usuario la imagen sigue seleccionada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ar">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Tamaño archivo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
         <input type="file" id="archivos" accept="image/*" name="archivos[]"/>
    </form>
    <script>
        function archivoSeleccionado(evt) {
            if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob){
                 var image = this.files[0].size;
                 if(image >= 3856819){
                       alert("La imagen es muy grande, El tamaño maximo es de 3.67 MB");
                 }else{
                       alert("La imagen tiene el tamaño adecuado");
                  }
            }

       }
       document.getElementById('archivos').addEventListener('change',    archivoSeleccionado, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: solo cambiale el valor a vació al input
document.getElementById("archivos").value = "";

Comment: para hacer eso tienes que usar AJAX Y PHP ejempo de mi code : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B05fuDZbqNIVbmt0MW8yaEd3Zm8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución clásica es asignarle un string vacío al elemento:

```
if(image >= 3856819) {
  alert("La imagen es muy grande, El tamaño maximo es de 3.67 MB");
  this.value = '';
}
```

Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que si das soporte a IE <= 10 y versiones de Firefox <= 45, no puede serte de mucha ayuda ya que no funcionará. Una solución sencilla es clonar el elemento, asignarle el string vacío y reemplazarlo por el original:

```
if (file.size > 3856819) {
  var clone = this.cloneNode();
  clone.value = '';
  this.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tama�o archivo


    
         
    
    
        function archivoSeleccionado(evt) {
            if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob){
                 var image = this.files[0].size;

```
             if(image >= 3856819){
                   alert("La imagen es muy grande, El tama�o maximo es de 3.67 MB");
             }else{
                   alert("La imagen tiene el tama�o adecuado");
              }
        }

   }
   document.getElementById('archivos').addEventListener('change',    archivoSeleccionado, false);
    function limpiar(){
        input=document.getElementById("archivos");
        input.value = ''
```

input.type = ''
input.type = 'file'

```
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onClick="limpiar()" value="Limpiar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te debe  funcionar

```
if(image >= 3856819) {
  alert("La imagen es muy grande, El tamaño maximo es de 3.67 MB");
  var inputImage = document.getElementById("archivos");
  inputImage.value = '';
}
```

Comment: No es necesario obtener nuevamente el elemento; `this` referencia al elemento.